# Try catch in jinja dbt Macros

Tags: macros, jinja2, dbt

I am trying to achieve try catch functionality in jinja inside dbt macros.
But it seems like jinja doesn't support it in macros.
Any alternative way I can achieve the same thing?

```
{% macro example_macro() %}

  {% for item in my_list_of_dicts %}
    {% set delete_query %}
         -- some logic
    {% endset %}

    {% try %} --how to achieve this in dbt macros
    {{ run_query(delete_query) }}
           
    {% except %}
        SELECT 'Error executing delete query for' AS errormsg
    {% endtry %}

  {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: I believe there is not try/catch in Jinja. Couldn't you just make it a conditional, and then if that condition is met you run `run_query(delete_query)`; otherwise, you log a warning/error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to use try/catch inside dbt macros. You can achieve a similar result using [execute variable](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/execute). Your snippet should look something like this:

```sql
{% macro example_macro() %}

  {% for item in my_list_of_dicts %}
    {% set delete_query %}
      -- some logic
    {% endset %}

    {% set result = run_query(delete_query) %}

    {% if not execute %}
      SELECT 'Error executing delete query for {{ item.some_identifier }}' AS errormsg
    {% endif %}

  {% endfor %}

{% endmacro %}
```

Keep in mind to replace *item.some_identifier* as it is just a placeholder for your actual column name.